# How do I migrate existing AWS IAM users to AWS SSO cross-account?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-sso, aws-control-tower

Currently, I have a bunch of IAM users in another account (not tied to AWS SSO).

I've recently started using AWS-SSO to manage multiple accounts and users. I found it very effective and easy to manage.

Question: How can I move/migrate users from another AWS account to AWS SSO in my current account?

I've found a few resources on how you can move an account to an organisation unit (OU) but I do not see any local users in the AWS SSO account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do this. You will have to either add the users into AWS SSO or integrate with an identity provider (Active Diretory, GSuite, etc)